# Xamarin.iOS binding with third party framework

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I am trying to update a Xamarin.iOS binding which points to code that I manage, and I'm having trouble now that I've replaced an external .a library reference with a .framework. Particularly, when I try to compile my binding, native linking is failing for the library which I replaced.

```
Native linking error: framework not found SVGKit for architecture arm64/i386/armv7/armv7s (MT5209)
```

I know for a fact that SVGKit supports these architectures, but I'm unsure how to include them in the generated binary when referencing from a .framework.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I would do this to diagnose the issue

First I would check if `SVGKit.framework/SVGKit`is a **fake framework** (static library disguised as a framework) or a dynamic one (**iOS 8+ support only**) using the `file` command on the binary

```
file Foo.framework/Foo
Foo.framework/Foo: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
Foo.framework/Foo (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
Foo.framework/Foo (for architecture x86_64):Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
Foo.framework/Foo (for architecture armv7): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
Foo.framework/Foo (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library

file Bar.framework/Bar
Bar.framework/Bar: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
Bar.framework/Bar (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
Bar.framework/Bar (for architecture i386):  current ar archive random library
Bar.framework/Bar (for architecture x86_64):current ar archive random library
Bar.framework/Bar (for architecture arm64): current ar archive random library
```

`Foo` is a dynamic library, notice the `Mach-O` and `Bar` is a static library disguised as a framework notice the `ar`

Now if it is a **fake framework** (static library) just take the `SVGKit.framework/SVGKit` binary and rename it to `SVGKit.a` and add it to your binding project, it should work as usual

If it is a **Dynamic Framework** then follow these [instructions on how to do it](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/).[0]

[0]: Just a side note, once Xamarin Studio 6.0 is out you will not need to manually modify the binding project `.csproj` file, you will be able to do it within the IDE itself :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've done as suggested and determined that it was a dynamic framework. I then followed the instructions, adding an element to binding's CSProj file with a ..\..\relative\path to the framework. Same build error, though. Also, no note of the the framework anywhere in the build log before the error.

Comment: mmm strange, you could take a look at a project I contribute to and have working here https://github.com/PSPDFKit/Xamarin-iOS/blob/master/PSPDFKit.iOS/PSPDFKit.iOS.csproj#L52-L54 and see if it works for you, it is using a dynamic framework too. Let me know if that works for you. Also if you share or have your project somewhere (i.e. github) I can have a look :)